# What are the most common attack patterns on a Smart Contract?

Tags: security, attacks

i'm new to Solidity. 
After writing my first smart contract im fairly concerned about it's security, once deployed to the MainNet. What are the most important things i should check within my code? Also are there any resources where i can learn about attack patterns?

Comment: What do you mean attacks? Do you know about how Ethereum works? What are smart contracts and how to access them?

Comment: A SmartContract is a program that lives and executes on the blockchain. One of the most popular languages for Smart Contracts is Solidity [link](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/solidity-by-example.html). Since a contracts code is not changeable once deployed, im extra concerned about potential security risks. There is a history people loosing millions due to bugs in Contracts [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_DAO_(organization))

Answer (score 1):

One handy guideline i found: https://medium.com/@merunasgrincalaitis/how-to-audit-a-smart-contract-most-dangerous-attacks-in-solidity-ae402a7e7868

The article is a step by step guide how to do a security audit for smart contracts.